# PDO select query return only the first row

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I am new at PDO. I was trying to retrieve data from the database by using a search keyword,
but I only get the first row in which the keyword is match. It doesn't return other rows.

Here is my code::

```
<?php
    $dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=cois';
    $user = 'root';
    $password = '';
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);


    $filmName = "shaban";

    $sql= "SELECT * FROM staff_info WHERE fname = :filmName";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':filmName', $filmName, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
    $total = $stmt->rowCount();

    while ($row = $stmt->fetchObject()) {
        echo $row->surname.'</br>';
     }
```

[image: Here is my table]

Currently it return only the first row.....it prints *shekidere*

How can i make it print both *shekidere and kimweri*

Any help?

Comment: You are using LIKE wild-card and its matching perhaps only one data.

Comment: Not that this makes a difference to your question, but why are you using `LIKE` when you are not using any sort of wildcard?  Outside of that, I don't know why your loop would only execute a single time with the data that you show in your example.  What happens when you run the query directly against the DB outside of PHP?

Comment: when i change `LIKE` to `=` it still return one result. And when i run it outside the php it also return first result, how is this possible?

Comment: Try `bindValue` rather than `bindParam` ... I've not thought it through yet but I think your *reference* is "shaban" rather than `$filmName`

Comment: i don know how, but when i change to this it return both rows. `$filmName = "male";

$sql= "SELECT * FROM staff_info WHERE gender = :filmName";`

Comment: It's possible you may have some whitespace around 'shaban' in the second row, try deleting the row and entering the data again.

Answer (score -2):

Of course it stops always on the first row. You can use `foreach` instead of `while` and use an `$arrayVariable[] = CurrentRow ;` to fill it next by next.